# detect the similar part and crop the part of an image

Tags: c#, python, .net, visual-studio, image-processing

how to compare a input image with a database image and crop the part from the image which part is similar as the image which is given into database? basically my input image should be a image which will carry the as image which is given in database along with some extra borders. this implementation could be in python or .NET. an anyone provide me some idea or code?

Comment: You will need edge detection, some heuristics, and a lot of fiddling around.. good luck... also your question is majorly off topic for stack overflow in its current format (close vote)

Comment: This question is very broad to be answered thoroughly. You can approach the problem from many sides and even try doing it with a neural network and machine learning to recognize "question papers" and extract them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the paper itself, this could be easily done with a white piece of paper : you set a specific pixel value where you think a pixel is bright enough to belong to the paper. You then verify that you have a bunch of pixels together passing the test (and not only an isolated few). This could make out the area where the paper is. However, this is very a rough and easy solution that will not give the best results. There is an whole field dedicated to images/videos and I don't think it's what you are looking for.

For a crop, if you can have the image in bitmap, there is the `Bitmap.clone`method : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944(v=vs.110).aspx.

You can specify the rectangle which will be your new image.

Answer (score 0):

First compare the images using opencv matchTemplate and crop.
Ref: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

```
# opencv
import cv2

# read input
image = cv2.imread(YOUR_IMAGE_PATH)
template_to_match = cv2.imread(YOUR_REF_IMAGE_PATH)

# convert it into gray
imageGray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    
templateGray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

# compare images using matchTemplate
result = cv2.matchTemplate(imageGray, templateGray, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
cv2.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, norm_type=NORm_MINMAX)
(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
(startX, startY) = maxLoc

endX = startX + template_to_match.shape[1]
endY = startY + template_to_match.shape[0]

cropImg = image[startY:endY, startX:endX]

cv2.imshow("cropped", cropImg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```